# Rolling computation based on a column's datetime values, and applied to another datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

The data I have is order creation and completion:

| OrderID | time_created | time_completed | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1/12/21 | 2/12/21 | 10 |
| b | 1/12/21 | 6/12/21 | 11 |
| c | 3/12/21 | 8/12/21 | 9 |
| d | 4/12/21 | 5/12/21 | 8 |
| e | 9/12/21 | 10/12/21 | 7 |

I am trying to do a rolling apply based on the time_created column, but applied to the time_completed column. Specifically, at the point of each new order creation, I am trying to filter for the previous x days of completed orders, and obtain distribution parameters from it (e.g. count, mean price, median price etc).

The most straightforward way that I can think of is to create a function that filters for the data of the relevant completed orders, then extracts the distribution parameters. This function would then be iteratively applied to each row in the dataframe. For example:

```
def get_params(ser):
    lookback = Timedelta('2d')
    past_orders = df[(df['time_completed'] < ser['time_created']) & (df['time_completed'] > ser['time_created'] - lookback)]
    mean = past_orders['price'].mean()
    25perc = past_orders['price'].quantile(0.25)
    count = past_orders.shape[0]
    return pd.Series([mean, 25perc, count])

df.apply(get_params, axis=1)
```

However, the problem of this implementation is that it is too slow. Each row's result is highly related to the previous row's results, but this implementation does not make use of it.

The time_created column is sorted, and always earlier/smaller than the time_completed column, which is why I believe some form of rolling can be used.

I guess my problem with pandas' rolling implementation is that I have not found how out to get it to reference one column (time_created) while rolling on another (time_completed). Is there any way to do that? Thanks.